# Mongod stuck in stop/waiting on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, mongodb, upstart

I installed MongoDB on Ubuntu 14.04 as per the documentation. It runs and works fine, except that it mysteriously stops every few hours and requires a manual restart with `service mongod restart` to get going again. There's nothing in the mongod.log when this happens.

In addition, when I restart and then check status with `service mongod status`, it gives me `mongod stop/waiting` event hough the application is able to connect to it. I've been searching around on how to debug this, but am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with OOMkiller killing the mongod process. As noted in the MongoDB production notes (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/administration/production-notes/#disk-and-storage-systems):

> Allocating swap space can avoid issues with memory contention and can
>   prevent the OOM Killer on Linux systems from killing mongod.

I used the below commands to create the swap file, which fixed the issue (on Ubuntu 14.04):

```
> sudo fallocate -l 2G /swapfile
> sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
> sudo mkswap /swapfile
> sudo swapon /swapfile
```

I then added the following to the `/etc/fstab` file to make this permanent:

> /swapfile   none    swap    sw    0   0

Answer (score -1):

You need to first uninstall the mongodb, you can use:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

After this, install mongodb by

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

And then update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You are done with the installation of mongodb. You can check it by using the below command:

```
mongo --version
```